# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'html'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the *Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'html'* error.

Javascript files included :

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/spin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Code Sample

```
$(this).closest('td').siblings()[6].html('Great');
```

Can you please help me track what is the issue.

Comment: Try this: `$(this).closest('td').siblings().eq(6).html('Great');` as `.siblings()[6]` returns a DOM object and `.html()` is jquery method, it doesn't work on DOM elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.html` is not a function of DOMNode.

Try:

```
$(this).closest('td').siblings().eq(6).html('Great');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

$(this).closest('td').siblings().eq(6).html('Great');